# When directly loading a Commerce 2 Order Item, why is the entity cached for anonymous users?

Tags: caching

I'm using the following to load a Commerce 2 Order Item:

```
    $order_item = \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderItem::load($order_item_id);
```

If I empty the cart for an anonymous user (thereby removing the Order Item), using the above code still loads the item as if it still exists.

The caching issue does not exist when logged in.

Why is the Order Item caches when loaded directly like I'm doing above?

How can I load a refresh version?

Comment: Might be a cache tag/context bug in Commerce, have you had a rifle through the issue queue just in case?

Comment: I just searched through the issue queue and didn't find anything related to this issue. I did open up a new issue though to see if it can be confirmed as a bug. Thank you.

Comment: I think the problem is not loading the entity, it's about rendering so that the output includes the cache tag of the entity.

Comment: Could you clarify on the issue please. Once I load the entity then, how can I clear the rendering cache to display the updated (non-existant) entity?

Comment: This is not how it works, you don't clear the cache in production, this happens automatically on CRUD operations for the entity. But you need to tag the rendered output properly, so that it can be invalidated when the entity is deleted.

Comment: Ah, got it. I naively did not realize that the entity was being cached by the form where to logic was running within. Simply setting    $form['#cache'] = ['max-age' => 0]; resolved it.

Comment: This is one way to do it, disabling caching altogether. Better for performance is probably to add cache tags: `$form['#cache']['tags'] = $order_item->getCacheTags();`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to the fact that the entity logic was running in a custom form and the form was caching the entity.

Simply setting:

```
   $form['#cache'] = ['max-age' => 0];
```

Resolved the issue.